# Как изменить/добавить css стили в административном разделе сайта

Tags: битрикс

Какие файлы редактировать или создать, что бы можно было не трогать ядро Битрикса?

Answer (score 0):

ну вообще
style.css отвечает за стили админки
template_style.css за стили фронта